# GWT: how to nest a TablayoutPanel inside a scroll Panel without specifying its exact height?

Tags: gwt, scroll, panel, gwt-tablayoutpanel

I need a scrollPanel with a verticalpanel and a tablayout panel inside it. Problem is, unless I specify the exact height of the tablayoutPanel, the tab content does not show. Any known fixes/ workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer you are looking for, but might spark an idea for another way to do this - what does it mean to scroll a tab panel? As soon as the user starts scrolling down, the tabs will no longer be visible to change tabs, user will always need to scroll all the way to the top to consider any other tab.

That said, any of the *LayoutPanel classes GWT has introduced that implement ProvidesResize, RequiresResize, etc need sizing to properly draw themselves and their content. This is why you are having the issue. These classes are designed to size their children, not to just consume as much space as those children require.

Closest I can suggest to a workaround (except for putting a ScrollPanel inside the TabLayoutPanel instead) would be to know the height of the current tab's contents, add to that the height of just the tabs themselves, and assign that as the height of the tabpanel. Not a very nice solution, but it might get you by.